# Getting data from Cursor in ListView OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter to display data from a Cursor in a ListView. When the user clicks a list item, the Cursor moves to the item position and retrieves some data from that row. Is this okay when I have already set an Adapter for the Cursor? Or should I move back to the first row when I'm done fetching data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the responsibility of anything using a `Cursor` to set its own position. Hence, you should not need to "move back to the first row when I'm done fetching data".